# How do I use reflection to execute an explicitly-implemented static abstract method

Tags: c#

Given the following interface that forces classes to implement a static method...

```cs
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    static abstract int GetNumber();
}
```

And two classes that both have two implementations of `IMyInterfacee<T>`

```cs
public class MyClass1 : IMyInterface<Company>, IMyInterface<Person>
{
    static int IMyInterface<Company>.GetNumber() => 1;
    static int IMyInterface<Person>.GetNumber() => 2;
}

public class MyClass2 : IMyInterface<Company>, IMyInterface<Person>
{
    static int IMyInterface<Company>.GetNumber() => 3;
    static int IMyInterface<Person>.GetNumber() => 4;
}
```

When I have a method in a consuming class like this

```cs
public int GetNumbers(Type classType, Type genericType)
{
  Type interfaceType = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
  return ??????
}
```

How would I implement `GetNumbers` so that I can call it like so

```cs
GetNumbers(typeof(MyClass1), typeof(Company)); // returns 1
GetNumbers(typeof(MyClass1), typeof(Person)); // returns 2
GetNumbers(typeof(MyClass2), typeof(Company)); // returns 3
GetNumbers(typeof(MyClass2), typeof(Person)); // returns 3
```

Comment: Do you explicitly not want to use generics?

Comment: What if first doesn't implement the interface? What if second doesn't match interface methods? First impression is that the GetNumbers signature isn't quite suited to how is supposed to be used.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. How would you call this even without reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface mapping ([`Type.GetInterfaceMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfacemap?view=net-6.0)) to find the method which implements the interface:

```cs
int GetNumbers(Type classType, Type genericType)
{
    Type interfaceType = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);

    // todo - check that class implements interface
    var interfaceMapping = classType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType);

    MethodInfo? methodInfo = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < interfaceMapping.InterfaceMethods.Length; i++)
    {
        var sourceMethod = interfaceMapping.InterfaceMethods[i];
        // simple predicate to find by name
        // possibly check that parameters are empty and return type is int
        if (sourceMethod.Name.Equals(nameof(IMyInterface<object>.GetNumber), StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            methodInfo = interfaceMapping.TargetMethods[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (methodInfo is null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Should not happen");
    }

    return (int)methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks! My real interface has more than one member, can you tell me how to get the one `GetNumber()`?

Comment: @PeterMorris you can use LINQ - `interfaceMapping.TargetMethods.Where(info => info.Name == "GetNumbers" && ...)` the predicate depends on what exact methods you have.

Comment: I've put that bit of code on pastebin, would you like to add it to the answer and then I'll accept it?  Thank you so much for your help! https://pastebin.com/3uXWgjqx

Comment: @PeterMorris added the filtering based on the docs example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a regular comment below Guru Stron's answer due to a lack of rep, but `GetInterfaceMap` is currently broken for interfaces that contain `static abstract` or `static virtual` members: Passing the type of such an interface unconditionally throws a `VerificationException`. See [dotnet/runtime#73658](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/73658).

Additionally, with there being two other reflection issues of interfaces with `static abstract`s linked to it, it seems that most of the reflection stack just doesn't work *at all* with such interface types. In that light, the only good answer I can give is "You just can't do this (until it's fixed (hopefully in a .NET 7 servicing update, but I'm not holding my breath))".

Comment: I originally got a BadImageFormat exception, but the accepted answer solved it for me.  Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Yep, `BadImageFormat` is probably [issue #79331](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79331).